# Can anyone solve the "PLANTERSPEANUTS Puzzle"?

Tags: recurrence-relations, puzzle

> **PLANTERSPEANUTS Puzzle**: In the early 1950's the makers of Planters Peanuts sponsored a contest and offered a prize to anyone who could determine the number of ways to spell PLANTERSPEANUTS by moving either downward, to the left, to the right, or any combination of these directions in the fifteen-rowed pyramid shown in the figure below.

```
               P
              PLP
             PLALP
            PLANALP
           PLANTNALP
          PLANTETNALP
         PLANTERETNALP
        PLANTERSRETNALP
       PLANTERSPSRETNALP
      PLANTERSPEPSRETNALP
     PLANTERSPEAEPSRETNALP
    PLANTERSPEANAEPSRETNALP
   PLANTERSPEANUNAEPSRETNALP
  PLANTERSPEANUTUNAEPSRETNALP
 PLANTERSPEANUTSTUNAEPSRETNALP
```

> Solve the PLANTERSPEANUTS puzzle by working parts (a) and (b).
>
> (a) If $T_n: n=1,2,\ldots$ denotes the number of ways in which one can spell an $n$-lettered word in an $n$-rowed pyramid, show that $T_n$ satisfies:
>
> $$ T_{n+1}=2T_n+1, T_1=1$$
>
> (b) Solve the initial-value problem in part (a) and use this result to solve the PLANTERSPEANUTS puzzle.

---

And here is my try:

I tried to form difference equation.

Assume that the no. of times an $n$-lettered word formed in and $n$-rowed pyramid is $T_n$

So:

$$\begin{align}T_1 = 1\\T_2 = 3\\T_3 = 7\\T_4 = 15\end{align}$$

and I tried to get an difference equation from this equations.

So I formed,

$$\begin{align}T_2 - T_1 = 2\\T_3 - T_2 = 2^2\\T_4 - T_3 = 2^3\\\vdots\\T_n - T_{n-1} = 2^{n-1}\end{align}$$

and I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.
.

Comment: Now added my try

Comment: You may want to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vMt3_6ki_M . (They seem to do what you did and then build upon that.) Note that the step "*$T_2-T_1=2, T_3-T_2=2^2, T_4-T_3=2^3$ so I conclude $T_n-T_{n-1}=2^{n-1}$*" is not justified either in your work or in the video (as far as I could see). I would prefer to see some direct combinatorial argument for $T_{n+1}=2T_n+1$, or a rigorous justification for the formula you found.

Comment: By the way, I cannot find that we have a duplicate of this on MSE, so it would be an interesting contribution if we could write it up properly as a MSE question (without images, using MathJax, following the advice you've been given above etc.) - I would probably then vote to re-open it.

Comment: Thank you for recommending the YouTube video. It solved the puzzle. In text book also having same answer.

Comment: The language is not understandable but I understood the steps. Now its clear for me.